# Convert any data to array buffer in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I'm not sure if I understand the concept of `UInt8Array` right, but I'm trying to convert any given data which can be `image/png,jpg,gif` `text/html,json,js,css,less` or any type of data including `octet binary` and then I can create data type `UInt8Array`

So, for any given data how can I convert them so I can make this possible?

```
var value = new Uint8Array([2, 4, 6, 8]);
```

Obviously that numbers in the array is hardcoded with random numbers, but the idea I think I want that part to be the data that I'm trying to convert to.

Answer (score 1):

If you can get the data in a Base64 string [MDN can help](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Base64_encoding_and_decoding#Appendix.3A_Decode_a_Base64_string_to_Uint8Array_or_ArrayBuffer) with this.

To sum up, use `base64DecToArr`

```
var myArray = base64DecToArr("QmFzZSA2NCDigJQgTW96aWxsYSBEZXZlbG9wZXIgTmV0d29yaw=="); // "Base 64 \u2014 Mozilla Developer Network"

var myBuffer = base64DecToArr("QmFzZSA2NCDigJQgTW96aWxsYSBEZXZlbG9wZXIgTmV0d29yaw==").buffer; // "Base 64 \u2014 Mozilla Developer Network"

alert(myBuffer.byteLength);
```